# How do I know where this instance is deallocated?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I got **[NSArrayM release] message sent to deallocated instance** error. However, the debugger hightlight a line in main source (retval line) instead of the line where this error actually happened. Any idea how to find this bug and fix it ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set conditional breakpoint when an exception occurs - that way debugger will stop exactly in the place of an error.

- To do that go to the breakpoints tab in Navigator section (leftmost xcode section).
- Click '+' at the bottom to "Add Exception Breakpoint"
- Add breakpoint (you can choose to catch only objective-c exceptions if you want)

Comment: It's still hightlighting retval line in main.m file but not where the exception actually occured!